# Regarding Visual Studio Forms Method Calling From Program.cs and general logic advice

Tags: c#, forms, visual-studio-2013

I'm trying to implement Blackjack via Visual Studio, but have just been introduced to it. Suppose I have a PictureBox representing a card in a hand. This box starts with an image of a face-down card, representing a card slot that hasn't been dealt to yet. I have a function in my Form object that changes the PictureBox image to another card image resource based on an integer parameter. This is all pretty standard.

What I'm having trouble with is actually calling the method from main. I could create a new Form object and set the auto-generated one to invisible, but I'd rather work with the form that's auto-generated. Should I just put all the game logic in the Form1.cs file? Does the auto-generated form object have some default name I can use?

I realize this seems pretty novice level, but it seems like Microsoft's support documentation would prefer you create entire projects from the designer view and doesn't help much for actually coding.

Answer (score 0):

The typical model for a simple Forms program is to allow the `Main()` method in Program.cs to remain in its default form: set some things up, create an instance of your primary `Form` subclass (the class name by default will be `Form1`), and pass that to the `Application.Run()` method.

It is good design to have a "controller" object outside of the UI object. But especially if you are starting out, you may well find it simpler and easier to understand if that "controller" logic is also in your primary `Form` subclass.

In that case, yes…all of the code winds up in the one .cs file, and indeed in the one object.

Even with the controller logic in the `Form` object, you will still find it useful to keep the code that is essentially controller logic separate from that which is user-interface logic, and to use the C# `#region` directive to label these sections of code. That will help you keep a mental model that still separates the two roles within the same class.

Beyond this, there are lots of differing opinions, from the complete "shoot-from-the-hip" approach, to the extremely strict and rigorous adherence to specific design patterns. But the above is consistent with the pattern that the Visual Designer leads you to, and so is a fine place for beginners to start.